# How to place a text over an image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place some text over an image and center it. I've looked around and the code I'm seeing isn't working for me. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

```css
.image img  {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 5px 10px 5px;
    
}

.image h1 {
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: 800;
color: black;
text-transform: uppercase;
transform: 50%;
font-size: 2rem;
position: absolute;
}

.image p {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 1rem;

    
    }
```

```html
<div class="image">
        <img src="grass.jpg"></img>
<h1>Big Cats Lawn Service </h1>
<p>Let the big cat tame your jungle</p>

</div>
```

Apologies if this is a dumb question, I'm trying to self teach myself. I'm on Mac OS Mojave using Visual Studio Code with live-server if that makes any differnce.

Comment: Can u share a visual of what you have achieved so far with you current code

Comment: Another approach would be use the image as a background for the element.

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
  <div class="center">center</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Source : [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property to make sure that you text is always over the image

And you can use [text-align](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp) to center the text

Code:

```
.image h1 {
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: 800;
color: black;
text-transform: uppercase;
transform: 50%;
font-size: 2rem;
position: absolute;
z-index:100;
text-align:center;
}

.image p {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    z-index:100;
    text-align:center;

    }
```